# Height map from image geometry node position

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, height-map

I'm making a flat mesh using a plane and geometry nodes. I am using a heightmap that I generated to displace the z for points on the mesh. However, the image is being transformed into a square and not sitting in the image correctly. I hope for it to be dead center with no transform.

This is what I have:
[image: Result and Geometry Nodes]

This is the source image:

[image: Depth map]

Comment: set the size of the grid to 1 m and use "Transform Geometry" node to move it by +0.5 m on $x$ and $y$, this way it has same coordinates as the UV space. Or do it the other way and convert your coordinates to the uv space when you sample the texture.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I did that but now it is just in the bottom corner still stretched to a square

Comment: You can use "Image Info" node to get the dimensions for the grid, and then use a map range to map the coordinates from position to UV coordinates

Comment: this doesn't really work/isn't clear could you add a photo?

Answer (score 0):

Try a setup like this:

[image]

I multiplied the resolution by $0.1$, because the image has high resolution and I wasn't sure if you can handle a dense plane. Similarly I multiplied the displacement by $0.1$, because the $y$ dimension of the image is normalized (always 1), so max displacement being 100% of the longer base dimension seemed too much…